# IBM Object Storage with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ibm-cloud, object-storage

I have some issue trying to save a file to IBM object storage via python. I copied the following credentials from the bluemix account (with details omitted below).

```
credentials = {
  "auth_url": "https://identity.open.softlayer.com",
  "project": <my project>,
  "projectId": <my project id>,
  "region": "dallas",
  "userId": <user id>,
  "username": <user name>,
  "password": <password>,
  "domainId": <domain Id>,
  "domainName": <domain Name>,
  "role": <role>
  }
```

And below is the python script that I have used trying to save a file to the container
    from io import StringIO
    import requests
    import json

```
url1 = ''.join(['https://identity.open.softlayer.com', '/v3/auth/tokens'])
data = {'auth': {'identity': {'methods': ['password'],
        'password': {'user': {'name': credentials['username'],'domain': {'id': credentials['domainId']},
        'password': credentials['password']}}}}}
headers1 = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
resp1 = requests.post(url=url1, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers1)
resp1_body = resp1.json()
for e1 in resp1_body['token']['catalog']:
    if(e1['type']=='object-store'):
        for e2 in e1['endpoints']:
                    if(e2['interface']=='public'and e2['region']=='dallas'):
                        url2 = ''.join([e2['url'],'/', container, '/', filename])
s_subject_token = resp1.headers['x-subject-token']
headers2 = {'X-Auth-Token': s_subject_token, 'accept': 'application/json'}
print(url2)
resp2 = requests.post(url=url2, data=filename, headers=headers2)
print(resp2.text)
return StringIO(resp2.text)

filename = "sample.png"<br>
post_object_storage_file("democontainer", filename)
```

I seems to get a token via resp1 and obtained url2. However, I get a 'Forbidden' response when i print resp2.text. I am the admin for that storage container so I don't see why I can't have access with this.

I am new to the IBM object storage so any advice will be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you paste the error?

Comment: https://dal.objectstorage.open.softlayer.com/v1/AUTH_1231413123d74ab89848eb8504e271bd/democontainer/sample.png
<html><h1>Forbidden</h1><p>Access was denied to this resource.</p></html>
<_io.StringIO at 0x7f6a3a0539d8>

Comment: Just to confirm, this is the OpenStack Swift based Object Storage available in Bluemix Services, and not the Cloud Object Storage that uses the S3 API and is available through Bluemix Infrastructure?

Comment: Nick. It looks to me the OpenStack Swift based Object Storage. To add abit more info, I am testing out their data science experience (jupyter notebook) platform and I am using python 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have is for reading objects from storage.

I would recommend you to use the "insert credentials" option in the Data Science Experience Data Import Panel and then use the swift client to save and read files from object storage. With Data Science Experience you can't reference files from your local hard disk, therefore I have given example of an image retrieved from the web.

Swift Client has the put_object function for saving objects.

```
import swiftclient
import keystoneclient.v3 as keystoneclient
from PIL import Image   ## To get image
import requests         ## To get image
from io import BytesIO


credentials = {
   ## Credentials HERE
}

conn = swiftclient.Connection(
key=credentials['password'],
authurl=credentials['auth_url']+"/v3",
auth_version='3',
os_options={
    "project_id": credentials['project_id'],
    "user_id": credentials['user_id'],
    "region_name": credentials['region']})



response = requests.get("URL to image file") ## Change to link to image file
img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))

conn.put_object(credentials['container'],"test.jpg",response,content_type='image/jpeg')
```

Comment: Fair enough. The particular image you chose is hosted on a site that spams Stack Exchange occasionally (see [here](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search?body=menshealth&commit=Search&feedback=&feedback_filter=tp&reason=44&site=&title=&user_rep_direction=%3E%3D&user_reputation=0&username=&utf8=%E2%9C%93&why=)), hence my comment.